# Split string by space and loop result to split by dash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

The command `nx affected:build --plain` gives me the single line output

```
domain.com-backend domain.com-frontend
```

I need to write this result in a file...

```
nx affected:build --plain > $FILE
```

...but also I need to split the content into elements (split by space) and each element into `domain` and `app` (split by dash) to generate multiple docker build commands.

I guess my attempt has a wrong syntax.

```
while IFS=' ' read -r element; do
    while IFS='-' read -r domain app; do
        echo docker build -t "$domain-$app" -f "apps/$domain/$app/Dockerfile" . # echo will be removed later
    done
done < $FILE
```

So the code should output two commands for the example:

```
docker build -t domain.com-backend -f apps/domain.com/backend/Dockerfile .
docker build -t domain.com-frontend -f apps/domain.com/frontend/Dockerfile .
```

Just for short summarize: The result string should be stored in a file and should result in a call of multiple generated commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example version to start, also has a tmp echo:

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile=./xyz.txt
info=($(nx affected:build --plain | tee $outfile))

for item in "${info[@]}"; do
    fb=${item##*-}
    echo docker build -t "$item" -f apps/domain.com/$fb/Dockerfile .
done
```

---

Updated:

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile=./xyz.txt
info=($(nx affected:build --plain | tee $outfile))

for item in "${info[@]}"; do
    dom=${item%-*}
    fb=${item##*-}
    echo docker build -t "$item" -f apps/$dom/$fb/Dockerfile .
done
```

Comment: How do I get domain and app variable? You hardcoded the domain...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution:

```
# instead of echo you can place your command (nx affected:build --plain)
data=`echo "domain.com-backend domain.com-frontend"`

IFS=' '
for part in $data
do
    while IFS='-' read -r domain app; do
        echo "docker build -t $domain-$app -f apps/$domain/$app/Dockerfile ."
    done <<< $part
done
```